# SQL server 2008 domain change

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In the near future, my organisation will have to change both the machine name and the Windows domain for one of our SQL servers.  The server is running SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Edition and the OS is Windows Server 2008 Standard edition.

I have found good references to handle the change of machine name, but can anyone help with what should be done to accommodate the change of domain?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only thing you'd need to change when you change your domain is the user account access on the server. When you installed SQL Server, the Setup process granted certain rights to the account you're using to run the SQL Service. If this was a domain account (ex. OLDDOMAIN\SQL_Proxy), then you'll need to grant those same rights to the proxy account on your new domain (ex. NEWDOMAIN\SQL_Proxy).

If, on the other hand, you're using "LOCAL SYSTEM" to run your SQL Service, you shouldn't need to make any changes at all, as this account will continue to have enough rights to run the SQL Service.

Please post back after you run this process - I'd be interested to know if you ran into any hurdles during the conversion.

Comment: Before changing the domain on the machine, make sure that you have a login that uses SQL server authentication that has full control over the databases that ISN'T a domain account (Windows Authentication), as you will no longer have access to that domain account.

Comment: @Fase - That's a good point, a SQL Account with SA rights would be helpful. Though it's one of the first things I do, I've noticed that most people don't remove "BUILTIN\Administrators" from the SQL Server, which has SA rights by default. If that group is still there, the local administrators on the servers will still have full rights on the SQL Server and can also be used to set up new domain users.