# How can I access SQL Server 2008 with windows authentication after my domain name changed?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need help in accessing a SQL server that I use for my research. I have local admin permissions on the OS (Windows Server 2008). My installation of SQL Server 2008 is set up to use windows authentication only. Unfortunately, our IT person (who is in another city) changed our domain name during an upgrade of our network over the weekend. I am now unable to access our databases through SSMS. I was able to convince our IT support to give me local admin permissions on the server, but am not sure how to get back into my data and fix the log in accounts. How do I go about reconnecting to my databases and what do I need to modify to ensure I have access to my data in the event that something like this happens again?

I tried using runas to login using my old credentials, but got nowhere. I've had a look at this question:
[SQL server 2008 domain change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049876/sql-server-2008-domain-change)

But that seems to focus on what to do BEFORE the domain change. I didn't get any warning about it and now need to fix the problem post-hoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to start the instance in single user mode as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx

After that just start SSMS with "Run as Administrator" locally and use windows authentication to connect. From there you can create a new login or rename the existing one.

After you recovered access restart the instance in normal mode.

Comment: Thanks, Sebastian. I'm not exactly sure why my question was closed (it's my first attempt at a question here and I'm a bit discouraged.) I'm attempting your solution but running into some challenges. I'd appreciate advice from folks on where I should go with this question if it's not appropriate here. It looks very similar to other questions I've seen here on SO.

Comment: That did the trick. I just had to start SQL Server in single user mode from the command line with the -m switch and then open SSMS using run as administrator.

Comment: Glad I could help. I don't understand why this was closed either. I think this question is better of at dba.stackexchange.com, but closing it seems a little over-reactive. May one of the close-voters can enlighten us? @KenWhite